# Caulking wood panels at bottom of bay window configuration

Tags: waterproofing, exterior, caulking, maintenance

A contractor doing some other work around the house noticed a small section of wood on the panel of the bay window in this picture was starting to soften. He recommended caulking the bottom to keep water from sitting there and getting behind the bottom area of the wood panel. I questioned him because some recommend keeping that area open for water to escape. Should I dig the caulk out or is it probably fine either way.
Thanks for your opinions.

[image]

Comment: Is that circled item a piece of flashing sticking out an inch or so over the flat panel below it? That seems... _odd_... Part of the problem may be that the panel recess is flat and not beveled so that every time it rains or snows, moisture can collect on that flat bottom piece and isn't naturally drained away by a slope.

Comment: Yes, it is a piece of metal drip edge flashing I believe.  And it does stick out some.

Comment: While I get the concept of the drip edge being there (it's probably actually "Z" flashing, and I'd guess it goes under the flat panel in the center), my guess is that it's actually helping to hold even more water at the joint until it evaporates off and is allowing the water more time to work its way into the joints between panels.

Comment: @Freeman - Yes.  I had similar situation where T-111 plywood siding was sitting on the Z flashing.  Like you said, the small gap would hold the water which would wick up into the open grain ends of the T-111, over time causing the lower inch or two of the siding to fall apart.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be in any hurry to caulk that up just yet. I'd be investigating why there's water down there. Check your entire bay window for any cracks in the frame or any cracked caulk on the outside. I'd also dig that old caulk out and slide in some paper towels just to get an idea of how much water was getting in there. If you do find some areas outside that are bad and recaulk them, you would be able to monitor your success with the paper towel method.

Comment: To clarify, the area that is circled was caulked by someone several months ago. So it is currently sealed and everything seems fine. I’m just wondering if that was an ok thing to do or if I should remove the caulk in the area that is circled.

Comment: @user109773  If the wood is softening, then you should investigate why.... soft wood is usually rotting and should replaced.  can you reach underneath there and check for dampness? Stick you camera under there and snap  few shots.

Comment: There was just a very small section on the right bottom corner of the panel that If you pushed on it there was a little give. Otherwise everything is structurally sound and there are no signs of dampness and nothing feels damp or any other visible signs of problems. The contractor was just wanting to do some preventative maintenance and felt like it might be related to the bottom area between the wood and the drip edge not being caulked. So he caulked and painted it. I’m just second guessing that decision now and wanted to see what other people thought about caulking that area vs not caulking

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to mess with it and that's understandable. Put it on your list of things to monitor.  With new construction or a repair, this is something I would have definitely caulked.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Would you caulk the top part of the recessed panel?  There has never been any there to my knowledge.

Comment: @user109773 at this point, no. Those recessed panels need to expand and contract a bit.